# signalR not working as expected

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr, azure-web-app-service

I am working on a maintenance project. The application is build on ASP.Net MVC4 and hosted on Azure cloud. It uses signalR. Now the issue is, signalR connection url gets Aborted after some interval. For this I have to restart the hosted app from Azure portal. But I can't do this each time when the client reports the issue. 
Please if any one could help or suggest or explain how this can be fixed and why this is happening.

Following logs I got in my browser console:

> SignalR: serverSentEvents transport failed to connect. Attempting to
>   fall back. SignalR: foreverFrame transport timed out when trying to
>   connect. SignalR: foreverFrame transport failed to connect. Attempting
>   to fall back. SignalR: longPolling transport timed out when trying to
>   connect. SignalR: longPolling transport failed to connect. Attempting
>   to fall back. SignalR: Fallback transports exhausted. SignalR:
>   Stopping connection. SignalR: Fired ajax abort async = true.

Thanks...

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: I have added some of the console log

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please check if the `Stop` method is called or you navigate away from the page in the client.

Secondly, many factors could cause disconnection issue. [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#connection-lifetime-terminology-and-scenarios) describes connection lifetime and some disconnection scenarios, which might help you find the possible causes of the issue.

Thirdly, timeout limit is reached while SignalR is attempting to re-establish a lost transport connection, please try to change/increase [Timeout settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#timeout-and-keepalive-settings) in `Application_Start`.

Besides, *continuously reconnect approach* could automatically re-establish a connection after connection has been lost and the attempt to reconnect has timed out, you could try it.

```
$.connection.hub.disconnected(function() {
   setTimeout(function() {
       $.connection.hub.start();
   }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

Comment: I don't think this will help - the connection is not even connecting... I think there is an issue on the server side that prevents from establishing a connection.

Comment: ``there is an issue on the server side that prevents from establishing a connection`` Yes, some issue with hub server could also prevent clients from establishing connection.

Comment: I was trying to debug and found $.connection.hub.state with outputs as 0 which is 'connecting'. And it directly moves to 'disconnected' state which is 4. It never gets connected